# as3 bitmap repeat-X and repeat-Y

Tags: actionscript-3

Quick question on Bitmap repeat x and y, i tried the following and it doesn't work

```
mySprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myFill);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
mySprite.graphics.endFill();
```

is it because you need to have a matrix

```
public function beginBitmapFill(bitmap:BitmapData, matrix:Matrix = null, repeat:Boolean = true, smooth:Boolean = false):void
```

Cheers
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function drawBackground():void {
    var clip:MovieClip = new GradientMovieClip();
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(clip.width, clip.height, true, 0xFFFFFF); // set the color to 0xFFFFFF if you use transparent png file for the pattern
    bd.draw(clip);
    _background.graphics.clear();
    _background.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bd);
    _background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, widthOfTheScreen, heightOfTheScreen);
    _background.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Problem solved